# Taglib Issue in Eclipse Maven-Imported Project

Tags: eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, jsp-tags

I'm trying to import a multi-module maven project into Eclipse which has multiple JSPs. The project uses techonologies in Spring framework including web & web MVC.

With the m2e plug I have imported the main POM which has created mulitple sub projects with correct dependencies etc. All seems just about ok with this.

The issue I'm having is that all the JSPs define the URI to the Spring-MVC taglib `spring.tld` as :

```
<%@ taglib uri="/spring" prefix="spring"%>
```

Yet the spring.tld file is at /WEB-INF/spring.tld, so I am seeing a lot of errors in Eclipse saying **Can not find the tag library descriptor for "/spring"**

This is not an issue at runtime in the resulting WAR as the web.xml file has the 'redirection' as :

```
    <jsp-config>
      <taglib>
         <taglib-uri>/spring</taglib-uri>
         <taglib-location>/WEB-INF/spring.tld</taglib-location>
      </taglib>
   <..>
   </jsp-config>
```

How do I tell Eclipse that for URI references to the taglib '/spring' to actually look fro '/WEB-INF/spring.tld', or just to ignore this and set it on the modules classpath using Maven dependencies ?

As I want to keep the source code as close to the original source pre-import, I don't want to go through multiple JSPs to fix this, nor do I want to rename and move the taglib to '/spring'.

Thanks

Comment: Where's the web.xml at development time? Is there something at that point in time that says where the tag library descriptor for `/spring` is located?

Comment: It's in the project src under /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to that will say that the tag libary descriptor for /spring is located. May be this is issue ?

Comment: Have you installed the m2e-wtp plug-in?

Comment: Yes this is installed